# Rails gem administrate custom values in fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I using administrate gem and the other day collided with this problem.How i can do something like this in my dashboard?

```
resource.owner.first_name
```

Or how i can put in field custom value using resourse variable?
In this moment i already tried this code and it working but with search broken with this approach:

```
%td= resource.owner.email
```